# Cannot convert ThreeBodyTB.CrystalMod.crystal{Float64} to series data for plotting

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook, julia-plots, pluto.jl

```
using Plots,ThreeBodyTB
begin
    A = [0 2.73 2.73; 2.73 0 2.73; 2.73 2.73 0] #angstrom lattice vectors
    pos = [0 0 0; 0.25 0.25 0.25]               #crystal coordinates
    atoms = ["Al", "P"]                         #strings or symbols are fine
    c = makecrys(A, pos, atoms)
end

c222 = c * [2,2,2]

plot(c222)
```

**
how do I fix this problem?

> Cannot convert `ThreeBodyTB.CrystalMod.crystal{Float64}` to series data for plotting.

I use Pluto notebook

[image]

WHEN I WRITE THIS CODE, A STRUCTURE LIKE THIS SHOULD COME. THE CODE DOES NOT WORK AND GIVES AN ERROR ON PLUTO NOTEBOOK.

**

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to plot. Could you explain in more detail, please? Remember not everybody does tight binding calculations, or even condensed matter ones involving crystal structures. (I do *ab initio* calcs but as I say I don't understand what you want).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.